# Ukuu Upgrading Error. GLib-GIO-CRITICAL

Tags: 18.04, gnome, kernel, updates, error-handling

I was upgrading my Kernel via Ukuu. My Ubuntu Distro (18.04.2LTS) is Up-To-Date. 
Does anyone know what this means? And how I can solve this? 
And is this really critical?

It still said the installation is complete and I could restart and no error anything similar happened.

[Error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMJLM.png)

Comment: GLib-Gio errors typically result from GUI apps, and usually not related to kernel itself. You may want to describe the exact steps and commands you used. Likely there is one application that relies on GIO

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy I literally just started the Ubuntu Kernel Update Utility program (Ukuu-gtk) and started it. I took the latest Kernel Version and clicked on install. Then the rest is fully automatic.

Comment: Ok so it is a Gtk app. I looked at the error again, there are no other errors following and installing the kernel followed as well, so I would not worry too much about it. If it does cause any issue with the kernel itself - you could submit a bug report to the developers. Otherwise, ignore it. Gtk has these quirks and it often comes down to things like buttons or windows in quick way ( like popup without parent window ). So dont worry about it

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy great hank you! I appreciate your help!